# Vue.js 3 template- literals error Cannot read property 'range' of null

Tags: vue.js, eslint, vuejs3, dynamic-import, async-components

I'm trying to dynamically import an async component in Vue.js.

```html
<template>
  <MyAsync></MyAsync>
</template>

<script>
import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue';

const component = 'lorem-ipsum-4';

export default {
  name: 'Article',
  components: {
    MyAsync: defineAsyncComponent(() => import(`@/articles/${component}.vue`)),
  },
};
</script>
```

This however does not work and produces the following error.

```
Failed to compile.

./src/views/Article.vue
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of null
Occurred while linting /project/src/views/Article.vue:13
    at SourceCode.getTokenBefore (/project/node_modules/eslint/lib/source-code/token-store/index.js:298:18)
    at checkSpacingBefore (/project/node_modules/eslint/lib/rules/template-curly-spacing.js:60:42)
    at TemplateElement (/project/node_modules/eslint/lib/rules/template-curly-spacing.js:119:17)
    at /project/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter/safe-emitter.js:45:58
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.emit (/project/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter/safe-emitter.js:45:38)
    at NodeEventGenerator.applySelector (/project/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter/node-event-generator.js:254:26)
    at NodeEventGenerator.applySelectors (/project/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter/node-event-generator.js:283:22)
    at NodeEventGenerator.enterNode (/project/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter/node-event-generator.js:297:14)
    at CodePathAnalyzer.enterNode (/project/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter/code-path-analysis/code-path-analyzer.js:634:23)
    at /project/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter/linter.js:936:32
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at runRules (/project/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter/linter.js:931:15)
    at Linter._verifyWithoutProcessors (/project/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter/linter.js:1157:31)
    at /project/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter/linter.js:1281:29
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

Static import however works just fine:

```html
<template>
  <MyAsync></MyAsync>
</template>

<script>
import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue';

export default {
  name: 'Article',
  components: {
    MyAsync: defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/articles/lorem-ipsum-4.vue')),
  },
};
</script>
```

This is a Vue.js v3 project created using Vue CLI.

A (quite minimal) example can be found at [github](https://github.com/bschnitz/vue-template-literals)

*Is there a way to make the dynamic import work?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging I found that it's an [eslint issue template-curly-spacing](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/template-curly-spacing), to solve it I added the file `.eslintrc` to the project root with following content :

```
{
    "plugins": [
        "vue"
      ],
    "rules" : {
        "template-curly-spacing": ["error", "never"]
      }
}
```

Comment: Great, You really got it! I would like to accept your answer, but unfortunatly it does not work with my setup. I found the correct syntax at https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/#usage. Did You add the .eslintrc to the example project I uploaded to github, or did You create a new project?

Comment: I cloned yours and I added the `.eslintrc` file with content above and its works

Comment: Ok, then I will accept it. For anyone who has problems with linting afterwards, I recommend using the configuration from the linke above with the additional rule from this answer.

Answer (score 3):

```html
export default {
  name: 'Article',
  components: {
    MyAsync: defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/articles/'+ component +'.vue')),
  },
};
```

But, I don't think this is good.

Comment: Pretty much exactly what he wrote but your answer is in the non ES6 variant (template litterals).

Comment: Thank You for the answer. Do You have any idea, why template literals do not work here? I don't have encountered any problems with them elsewhere. Also why do You think, that this is not good?

Comment: @LordBo template literals should work as mentioned here https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-ts-y7bdv?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229743/discussion-between-lord-bo-and-boussadjra-brahim).

Answer (score 0):

Replace `@` on a path consisting of `./`

```
export default {
  name: 'Article',
  components: {
    MyAsync: defineAsyncComponent(() => import(`./articles/${component}.vue`)),
  },
};
```

It worked for me

Comment: Thank You for your answer. Unfortunatly, that doesn't change anything for me.