# Dynamic import of component fails

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I'm trying to implement the recommendation of [this article](https://itnext.io/vue-a-pattern-for-idiomatic-performant-component-registration-you-might-not-know-about-9f3c091846f5) on component dynamic import:

Template:

```
<component :is="componentLoader" />
```

Script:

```
computed: {
  componentLoader () {
    const modalComponent = 'HeroBanner'
    return () => import(`@/components/template-ux/${modalComponent}.vue`)
  }
}
```

But I'm getting an error:

> Cannot read property 'value' of null - Occurred while linting
> D:\projects\my-project\components\global\Modal.vue:41

What is causing this issue?

EDIT: line #41 is the line starting with `return () => import...`

Comment: which vue version are you using? I had a similar question about vue 3, [which was answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66862450/11869100).

Comment: it seems that is an eslint config issue, please check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66572162/8172857

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to change anything in my case

Comment: It is clearly an eslint issue. Update your question with version information about eslint and it's plugins. Also try to replace template literal (one of the answers to question linked in comments)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the component that you are loading is missing some props maybe.
You can pass you props dynamically like so:

```
<component :is="componentLoader.component" v-bind="componentLoader.props"/>
```

```
computed: {
  componentLoader () {
    return {
       component: () => import(`@/components/template-ux/${modalComponent}.vue`),
       props: {
           value: 'Something'
           foo: 'Foo'
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what's happening in your file, you sometimes cannot dynamically import a component. Let's say if you need some values right when rendering the template. Here, there is a case where you do try to access a value with `.value` on something not here yet.

Solution would be to import it the classic way, or to make some validations on the elements, for example `modal?.inputText?.value` thanks to [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (working only in the `<script>` section btw).

Please show us the content of `Modal.vue` to see what is happening here.